# Find Duplicate Rows/Records from Table

Tags: php, sql

Here is my table structure,

[image]

Im try run query

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT content,niche, COUNT(content) TotalCount FROM table_name GROUP by content HAVING COUNT(content)>=2");
```

I i think is give me corect result, but have problem to list result with php and make delete button to delete one of duplicated rows

Im get result in php

**Content ID** - **Niche ID** - **TotalCount** 
208 - 2 - 2 
210 - 32 - 3

But result should be

**Content ID** - **Niche ID** - **TotalCount**  
208 - 2 - 2 
208 - 2 - 2 
210 - 32 - 3 
210 - 32 - 3 
210 - 32 - 3

im try result display with php

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {            
    $array[] = $row;
}
foreach($array as $row) {
    echo $row['content']." - ".$row['niche']." - ".$row['TotalCount']."<br>";
}
```

Comment: Since the result you need is (TotalCount) times each row, what is the problem with the first one ?

Comment: Need to make button and delete double row,

Comment: @MilanMilosevic maybe you can use distinct instead of deleting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're asking for, all duplicate rows (with row_id) and how many times they are duplicated;

```sql
SELECT a.row_id, a.content, a.niche, cnt
FROM table_name a
JOIN (
  SELECT MIN(row_id) m, COUNT(*) cnt, niche,content
  FROM table_name
  GROUP BY content,niche
  HAVING COUNT(*)>1
) b
  ON a.niche=b.niche
 AND a.content=b.content
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b0424/1).

Answer (score 2):

`GROUP BY` will collapse the results on the field you're grouping, in this case `content` - hence why you only see two results.

If you want to keep the `GROUP BY` technique, you can also use `GROUP_CONCAT(niche)` to pull a comma-separated list of each `niche` for a given `content` value:

```
SELECT
    content,
    GROUP_CONCAT(niche) AS niche,
    COUNT(content) TotalCount
FROM
    table_name
GROUP BY
    content
HAVING
    COUNT(content)>=2;
```

You can then use PHP's `explode(',', $row['niche'])` to get each distinct value and then use those to determine which one you want to delete.

```
foreach($array as $row) {
    $niches = explode(',', $row['niche']);
    foreach ($niches as $niche) {
        echo $row['content'] . " - " . $niche . " - " . $row['TotalCount'] . "<br />";
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm this is back me all result from table, need to find just a double

Comment: @MilanMilosevic It's a copy+paste of the query from your question with the addition of `GROUP_CONCAT()`; there's no way it could return all of the results from your table unless your table is full of duplicates. If you're still having issues with it, can you setup a sample at http://sqlfiddle.com ?

Answer (score 0):

Make the following change in sql:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT content,niche, COUNT(content) TotalCount FROM table_name HAVING COUNT(content)>=2");
```